# An error occurred while installing autoprefixer-rails (5.2.1.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I want to install bootstrap-sass for rails app, but failed.

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5' #add it to Gemfile
```

then `bundle install`

```
Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /Users/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/autoprefixer-rails-5.2.1.2.gem. It may be corrupted.
An error occurred while installing autoprefixer-rails (5.2.1.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install autoprefixer-rails -v '5.2.1.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

then I tried to run the command `gem install autoprefixer-rails -v '5.2.1.2'`, but still doesn't work.

```
ERROR:  Error installing autoprefixer-rails:
    invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in /Users/liuxingqi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/autoprefixer-rails-5.2.1.2.gem
```

Rails version: 4.2.3

ruby version:  ruby 2.2.2p95

Anyone can help me!

Comment: As the error message says, try running `gem install autoprefixer-rails -v '5.2.1.2'`.
Please post the the logs for it if that errors out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I delete the gem package from cache directory, then run `bundle install`, everything is ok.

```
 rm /Users/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/autoprefixer-rails-5.2.1.2.gem
 bundle install
```